# np.array arr.itemsize vs sys.getsizeof(arr[0])

Tags: python, numpy, types, numpy-ndarray

Given an array

```
arr = array([  9.93418544e+00,   1.17237323e+01,   1.34554537e+01,
         2.43598467e+01,   2.72818286e+01,   3.11868750e+01,...])
```

When executed following commands I get some output:

```
arr.itemsize # 8
type(arr[0]) # numpy.float64
sys.getsizeof(np.float64()) # 32
sys.getsizeof(arr[0]) # 32
arr.dtype # dtype('float64')
```

It seems that itemsize doesn't work properly. I'm interested why does it happen?

I work with

```
print(sys.version)
3.5.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 24 2018, 01:52:17) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
numpy==1.10.4
```

Comment: It does, there is a difference between a *Python object*, and the size an element takes in Numpy. Note that numpy is implemented in C++, and does not constructs individual "pyton objects".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems that itemsize doesn't work properly.

It does, the different results are due to the fact that a Python object, is different from an item in numpy.

In Python, everything is an object. The data is "boxed". That means that for example for an `int`, we get:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(2)
28
```

That is 28 bytes. That is a lot. In most programming languages, an `int` takes between two and eight bytes. If it is 32-bits `int`, then that takes 4 bytes.

But in Python, an object has a lot of "context". For example some bytes are used to denote the type of the object, etc.

Numpy however is *not* implemented in Python, it is not a library that uses Python objects itself. It is more a library implemented in C, and with a nice interface to Python. This thus means that a list `[1, 4, 2, 5]` is not stored in Python as a list with four references to `int` objects, but as an array, usually with "unboxed" elements. So the above will take, given the `int`s take 32 bits each, 4*32 bits and some extra space for the "context" around the array.

Items are thus stored in a more space efficient way. This makes processing the values easier, since we do not follow pointers here, but the values directly (there are ways to store references in an numpy array, but let us ignore that for now). Furthermore a numpy array takes thus far less memory than the equivalent Python list (together with the items it holds) would do.

If you however fetch an item from a numpy array, one needs to make a Python object for that. So that means that here it will construct a `numpy.float64` object, that contains the value, but again a lot of "context" around that value. This results in using more memory.

The fact that numpy constructs an array of a certain type of objects, also has some consequences. For example if you use a `numpy.int16`, then that means one can not store values larger than 32767 into them, since that value can not be represented with a 16-bit 2-complement representation:

```
>>> np.int16(32767)
32767
>>> np.int16(32768)
-32768
```

Furthermore one can not - without using Python object references or some other "tricks" - construct an array that contains objects of different types. Numpy constructs for example an array of `int16`, so that means that it interprets the 160 bits as 10 16-bit numbers. In Python a list itself contains a reference to objects, and a Python object knows what type it is, so that means we can set the reference to another object, of another type.

Comment: "In CPython it has also two pointers: one to the next, and one to the previous object on the heap." Nope. For a plain `PyLongObject` on 64 bit Python, the cost is the pointer to type (8 bytes), reference count as `ssize_t` (8 bytes), length field as `ssize_t` (8 bytes), and the array (in this case of size 1) of 32 bit (4 byte) integers representing the magnitude (4 bytes). There's no doubly-linked list of allocations for plain `int`s (there is something like this for objects that participate in cyclic garbage collection, but not for immutable objects that don't contain other Python objects).